# How to use functonal of ViewBinder in SimpleExpandableListAdapter?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In my app i need to override ViewBinder of ListView SimpleAdapter.
Now I need to use ExpandableListView but cant figure out how to realize this functional? There is no ViewBinder.

Googling give no result. Does anyone previously was not interested in a solution, or it so obvious but I did not notice?)